# JS - disable select elements

Tags: javascript

I've a question related with JS. I'm pretty new to this!

I've [combo-box] with n elements.

I also have function called "getValues()" which returns listbox elements such as:

```
array (size=5)
'value' => string '...' (length=25)
'level' => int 1
```

Right now, user sees combobox with elements (value). Everything works perfect, but I want to make JS function, that would do following:

When user clicks one element from combobox(select), other elements from listbox, which 'level' is lower (<) gets auto-disabled (impossible to click).

I tried something like this, but stopped, because I mainly focus on php and am just learning JS right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function JS(){
if(document.getElementById('types').value) 
{
var id = document.getElementById('types');
for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
if( allelements.level < selected.level) 
? op[i].disabled = true 
: op[i].disabled = false ;
}
```

Current function is written in pseudo-code [also not finished].
Maybe someone could write properly functioning js code for what I want. I haven o clue how can I access that arrays values 'level' for instance and so on. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: try with `class` . `id ` is unique

Comment: `document.getElementById('types')` returns only 1 element at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is asking for the code to be written, here's what it looks like:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var index = select.selectedIndex;
    var children = select.children;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (i <= index) {
            children[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
        } else {
            children[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
    <option>Six</option>
</select>
```

Basically we take the index of the selected option, check if each child's index is less or greater and set the disabled attribute based on that.